# Iterating two lists of arrays(Parallel) [python]

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, zip

I'm tryin to iterate in parallel two lists which contain 100 array each for example list one:
[list1 (list of length 100 each element being a (2482,) array)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuj8l.png)
here's list two:
[list2 (list of length 100 each element being a (2482,) array)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9W3y.png)

The idea is to extract the valid data ("True") from list 2 for each array in the list using np.extract.

I tried:

```
      validdata=[] 
      for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
           extractdata=np.extract(i,list2[j])
           validdata.append(extractdata)
```

which returns the Type error "only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index", the same happens with map(None,list1,list2)

Thanks

Comment: So these are lists of tuples?  `l[(1,)]` isn't a valid index

Comment: I think what you want is `extractdata=np.extract(i,j)` or more simply `i[j]`

Comment: Yes apologies, I've edited it now

Comment: looks to me like np.arrays, not tuples...

Comment: Thanks @Julien Bernu, that fixed it, oops

Answer (score 0):

Removing the extraneous code, the following would suffice.

```
validdata=[] 
for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
    validdata.append(j[i])
```

Readers may validate the code with this input:

```
list2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
list1 = np.array([[True, False, True], [True, True, False], [False, True, True]])
```